# Need Help In SQL For Date

Tags: sql

01/12/2016, 02/12/2016, 03/12/2016

In SQL I had a these three dates in single record or single cell, but I want to take first date as `from date` and last date as `end date`.

I need any syntax for that. Can some one help me?

Comment: Decide single record (multiple columns) or one column with CSV

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: Comma separated values is a mess and will only cause you lots of trouble... One value per row is the SQL way.

Comment: You should do that in your application end rather in DB.

Comment: I try lot but i can't get the required answer

Comment: one value per "cell" is the right way (you could have all 3 dates in a single row of 3 separate columns)  also use the correct data type, right now that "cell" contains a string that **might be converted** into dates. i.e. you cannot ensure the integrity of your data. By the way I assume you are using DD/MM/YYYY but it is possible those 3 example are Jan 12, Feb 12, and March 12. That is just another possible issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the data structure is same for all values, then you can try as below

```
DECLARE @val AS TABLE (val NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @val 

SELECT'01/12/2016, 02/12/2016, 03/12/2016'


SELECT *FROM  @val

SELECT CAST (LEFT(val,10) AS DATE) AS startdate , CAST (RIGHT(val,10) AS DATE) AS enddate FROM @val
```